# Regex: Search within match

Tags: php, regex

This is the source:

```
<item>
  <title>Quarterly Report ( Third Quarter 2013 )</title>
  <link>http://www.example.com/reports/Q3 2013_Final.pdf</link>
  <pubDate>24 Oct 2013 00:00:00 +0500</pubDate>
</item>
```

I need to replace the space with `%20`, within the URL only.

How do I go about doing it?

Edit: The source data comes from another website which I have no access to and I do not want to parse the XML just for replacing the space character.

Comment: x.substring(x.indexOf("<link>")+6, x.indexOf("</link>")).replace(" ", "%20")

Comment: I am trying to do this in PHP and with `preg_replace` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your comment that you are using php.

What about this one

```php
function FixSpace($match)
{
    $out  = $match[1];                          // opening tag
    $out .= str_replace(' ', "%20", $match[2]); // url
    $out .= $match[3];                          // closing tag

    return $out;
}

$input = preg_replace_callback("~(<link>)(.*?)(</link>)~", "FixSpace", $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

First select link tag and the contents using regex ".*</link>" and then replace space I.e. \s with %20

I have written example using ruby langauge.

```
str= "<item>
```

Quarterly Report ( Third Quarter 2013 )
  http://www.example.com/reports/Q3 2013_Final.pdf
  24 Oct 2013 00:00:00 +0500
"
    str.scan(/.*</link>/).first.gsub(/\s/,'%20')

Comment: Please upvote if you Like answer.